# iPHONE device not recognised by Xcode, iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode7, itunes

I was working in `Xcode 7.3.1` every thing was working fine, then suddenly Xcode app stop recognising my device. I have already gone through all the links, blogs about that issue but couldn't find any success. The complete configuration is as follows -

- `Xcode 7.3.1`
- `OS 10.11.5`
- `iOS 9.3`
- `iTunes 12.3.3.17`

its not getting recognised by `iTunes` as well but Photos app recognised it only when i restart the computer, Afterwards photo app also not able to recognised.

Comment: Some times it hapens, Try to change the usb port..

Comment: i hav done every thing possible.... changing usb port , usb cable , iPhone device .... not working at all

Comment: In you iPhone which os is running, Is it iOS 9.3 that you mentioned ot iOS 10.

Comment: refer this, https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204095 @AnuragBhakuni

Comment: This is a known bug in OS X. Sometimes it just loses the ability to talk with iOS devices, and rebooting the Mac is the only (temporary) fix. (If anyone from Apple sees this, please look up rdar://26528150).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help others as well

Before trying solution which work for me, you should try the following thing also:-

1. Restart the mac and iPhone device
2. Use different port and connecting wire.
3. Pls make sure your device Trust your computer.

   If none of the above methods work for u, then you can try updating to the newest version of iTunes or  delete the iTunes and download it again.